# MyEclipse does not recognize JSF tags

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myeclipse

I am new to JSF 2

I have tried to setup a sample JSF 2 Web application, but I have a problem.

I am using myeclipse 8.6 and weblogic 10

I have created a new Web project in myeclipse. Then I added facelet 1.1 and myfaces 2.0.4 libraries to the classpath of my project. I also have added primefaces 2.2.1 API to my project. Then I tried to create a new XHTML file.

My Eclipse does not recognize some tags like `"<h:head> and <h:body>"`, and it does not 
recognize primefaces tags. I still have problem with this.

What should I do?

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete problem: Facelets 2.0 is already included in JSF 2.0. You should remove the old Facelets 1.1 library, otherwise you will run into class version conflicts during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the tag libraries in your XHTML file ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
</html>
```